# Error Jboss 7.1 Debug Remoto

Tags: java, jboss, depuración

Tengo un webservice soap desplegado en un Jboss 7.1.

Cuando levanto el servidor, me sala la siguiente traza:

> 2019-09-14 18:00:31,775 - ERROR - (Remoting
>   "desktop-qkfs033:MANAGEMENT" read-1): JBREM000200: Remote connection
>   failed: java.io.IOException: Received an invalid message length of
>   1195725856 (RemoteConnection) 2019-09-14 18:00:31,780 - ERROR -
>   (Remoting "desktop-qkfs033:MANAGEMENT" read-1): JBREM000200: Remote
>   connection failed: java.io.IOException: Received an invalid message
>   length of 1195725856 (RemoteConnection) 2019-09-14 18:00:33,532 -
>   ERROR - (Remoting "desktop-qkfs033:MANAGEMENT" read-1): JBREM000200:
>   Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException: Received an invalid
>   message length of 1195725856 (RemoteConnection) 2019-09-14
>   18:00:33,538 - ERROR - (Remoting "desktop-qkfs033:MANAGEMENT" read-1):
>   JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException: Received
>   an invalid message length of 1195725856 (RemoteConnection)

He probado a cambiar los puertos por defecto:

- 9990 = 8990
- 9999 = 8999
- 9443 = 8443

Sin embargo sigue producuiendose el mismo error.